# react-router get current route from upper component

Tags: path, react-router

I have something like this:

```
render(
  <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ App } >
      <IndexRoute component={ Home }/>
      <Route path="/a" component={ A }/>
      <Route path="/b" component={ B }/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and I want to get the current location on the App component. How can I achieve this? Already tried using `this.props.location` but it's `undefined`.
I'm using react-router 3.0.0